# Kotlin : How to use Kotlin Room to generate a unique id

Tags: kotlin

in my application ,apart from the primarykey of a user ,I will still need to generate a unique ID(12 -15 charactors) for showing to the public .

I am new with Room ,Could you please take a look my code ?

Thank you so much in advance !

```
@Entity
data class UserInfo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val userId:Int = 0,
    val image: String,
    val imageSource : String,//Local or Online
    val username : String,
    val gender :String,
    val userPublicId:String, //this is the id that need to generate 12-15 
    val birthday : String,
    val userIntro :String,
   
)
```

Comment: Room doesn’t generate keys with arbitrary requirements like that. You can search for ways to generate random Strings in Java and will find many possible different ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much ,I will try to find out more ways .

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned @Tenfour04 you can use some ways to generate random string. I think `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils` is a good choice. For exmaple look at the following methods: `randomAscii`, `randomAlphabetic`, `randomAlphanumeric`.

Comment: Thank you so much ,I will take a look if this could work .